# Write data to file Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, encryption, nsdata, writetofile

I need to use the  `writeToFile:` methods in writing data (that is encrypted) to a file. However, say I have:

```
NSData *encryptedData = [data AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
```

And I write the encryptedData to a file by:

```
[encryptedData writeToFile:@"file.txt" automatically:YES];
```

This for some reason does not write the data to "file.txt." This is a very simple question and I know I am missing something super basic. If file.txt is not actually there, it must be created.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not write"? Does a file named `file.txt` appear in the executable's directory?

Comment: I need "file.txt" to show up in my desktop and in the documents folder. Sorry, I was not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably has nothing to do with Cocoa or `NSData`.

On Unix (like Mac OS X), paths that start with `/` are absolute. Paths that start with `~` are relative to the current user's home directory. Anything else (such as `file.txt`) is relative to the current directory. When running something from Xcode, that is the path of the executable (the compiler's output path).

So, to write that to the desktop, that would be:

```
[encryptedData writeToFile:@"~/Desktop/file.txt" atomically:YES];
```

For the documents folder, that would be:

```
[encryptedData writeToFile:@"~/Documents/file.txt" atomically:YES];
```

Don't forget that paths are also case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes I know, I've edited it. I incorrectly copied and pasted from my project. However, it still does not do anything.

Comment: @Bobby There, I changed my answer.

Comment: Hard coding paths is a bad idea. Try this: `[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"]`

Comment: You need to call stringByAppendingTildeInPath maybe? Or else expand the tilde yourself just to test if it works.

Comment: Rob, quick question, how would I add an extension over "file.txt," so I could have whatever the filename would be plus '.myextension"? Like [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] -> and then ofType:@"";? How would I add an extension over whatever I want the filename to be (as an nsstring)

Comment: Or just have the extension and filename separately, like file: of type:? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

returns a boolean to say if it was successful or not. I'd start there, if you see a YES then the file wrote somewhere successfully.

If that doesn't work then i'd double check the object you're trying to encode supports the [NSCoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. If you object doesn't support NSCoding take a look at [this](http://davedelong.com/blog/2009/04/13/aspect-oriented-programming-objective-c) blog post for a nifty simple way of adding it.

Also its "atomically" not "automatically" :)